# What is the difference between BSA fraction V and the initial fraction?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture

I am preparing a supplemented culture medium and I need to use BSA. There is fraction V of BSA that we normally use for immunocytochemistry and there is another type named the initial fraction that is specific for cell culture but we don't have enough amount in the lab currently.
I want to know whether or not I may use the fraction V for cell culture as well.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Who is the manufacturer/provider and have you tried looking this up yourself? I searched using "BSA fraction V" and [this was my top result](https://www.goldbio.com/product/3662/bovine-serum-albumin-bsa-fraction-v-protease-free#:~:text=Fraction%20V%20refers%20to%20the,albumin%20regardless%20of%20purification%20method.).  Please note that the expectation on this site is that you will demonstrate that you have done some prior research before posting. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: For an extremely specific question like this, I think you will increase the probability of getting a helpful response if you include the actual details of the reagents.  In other words, for me to order those same two types of BSA I would need to know at least the manufacturer's name(s), and the catalog number(s).  From that one could possibly bootstrap their way to an answer. Also, after clicking on the link from @tyersome, I did a quick search and found this Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn_process that describes the steps.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
Yes. I checked the manufacturer's protocol, the datasheet, and research gate beforehand but I could not find anything specific. I also asked my supervisor's idea but I was not convinced to use it so I kept on looking for more information. Thank you for the links you shared. I will check them. 
By the way, I used the fraction V BSAfor supplementing my culture medium and so far the cells are fine. 
The ref number for BSA's:
Bovine serum albumin fraction V REF10735086001, ROCHE
Albumin, Bovine initial fractionation by heat shock, A7906, Sigma

Thank you.